# Filtering roles by name Discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, autocode

I have an array with all the roles in a Discord server, and I want to filter it to show me only the roles which have a specific name. I've used the `filter()` function before for filtering members with a specific role, but I am having trouble adapting it to this situation.

The code for filtering a list of members:

```js
const membersWithRole = members.filter(m => !!m.roles.find(r => r === sheet.rows[i].fields.role_id));
```

Comment: Add sample input and output

Comment: The problem is likely with `r === (some id)`, `r` is your current role object and cannot equal a string. Try `r.id === ...` Also use `Array.some()` instead of `.find()` since you want a boolean. Saves you from having to use `!!`

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get what you really trying to do but I guess you must be trying to get role that `starts with` or `contains` certain name.

For starts with certain name:

```js
let roleName = "filtering_name"
const role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name.startsWith(roleName))
```

For contains certain name:

```js
let roleName = "filtering_name"
const role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name.includes(roleName))
```